# Is secured entry possible for api.ai intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, bots, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am trying to do agent training using api.ai.
I wanted to read a secret key from user expression. Is it possible to allow the user text entry in secured format (Like we enter passwords - the big black dots)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EditText with the **inputType** set to **textPassword** like this:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```